# Infowindow re rendering whole google map with thousands of marker everytime

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

So, I am new to react and trying to add markers and their infowindow in google-maps-react. Also, I m getting thousands of marker location from API.

Every time a marker is clicked and its relative infowindow is opened, it again renders the whole of thousand of marker again, which is time taking and not so fun.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
  import DRINKING_WATER_PUMP from './pins/Drinking_RMS_Absent.png'
  import ROOFTOP from './pins/Rooftop_RMS_Absent.png'
  import IRRIGATION_PUMP from './pins/Irrigation_RMS_Absent.png'
  import PATVAN from './pins/Patvan_RMS_Absent.png'
  import MINIGRID from './pins/Minigrid_RMS_Absent.png'
  import farmer from './pins/CCAFS-image.png'
  const mapStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position:'relative',
    display: 'flex', 
    flexFlow: 'row nowrap', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
  };
  export class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          showingInfoWindow: false,  //Hides or the shows the infoWindow
          activeMarker: {},          //Shows the active marker upon click
          selectedPlace: {}          //Shows the infoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
        };
        this.onMarkerClick=this.onMarkerClick.bind(this)
        this.onClose=this.onClose.bind(this)
      }
    onMarkerClick(props, marker, e){
      console.log('on click called:')
      this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
      });
    }
    onClose(props) {
      if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
        this.setState({
          showingInfoWindow: false,
          activeMarker: null
        });
      }
    }
    render() {
      console.log('render')
      return (
        <Map id="map"
          mapTypeControl={false}
          gestureHandling= {'greedy'}
          zoomControl= {false}
          streetViewControl={false}
          fullscreenControl={false}
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={5}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{
           lat: 21.5937,
           lng: 78.9629
          }}
        >
          {
            this.props.datapins.map((marker, index) => {
              let assetType=marker.assetType
              let icon={
              url:'' ,
              anchor: new this.props.google.maps.Point(12,23),
              origin: new this.props.google.maps.Point(0,0),
              scaledSize:  new this.props.google.maps.Size(20,20)
              }
              switch(assetType){
                case 'PATVAN':icon.url=PATVAN; break;
                case 'MINIGRID':icon.url=MINIGRID; break;
                case 'IRRIGATION_PUMP':icon.url=IRRIGATION_PUMP; break;
                case 'DRINKING_WATER_PUMP':icon.url=DRINKING_WATER_PUMP; break;
                case 'ROOFTOP':icon.url=ROOFTOP; break;
                default: break;
              }
              return (
              <Marker key={index} icon={icon} position={{lat: parseFloat(marker.lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.lng)}} onClick={this.onMarkerClick}  />
              )
            })
          }
          <InfoWindow className="infoWindowCard"
            pixelOffset={new this.props.google.maps.Size(170,380)}
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
            onClose={this.onClose}
          >
            <div style={{'overflow':'hidden'}}>
              <img src={farmer} alt='farmer' className="infoWindowImg"/>
              <h4 className="infoWindowName"> Satpal Singh </h4>
              <h6 className="infoWindowName"> Customer ID: 007 </h6>
              <div>
              <ul className="infoWindowDetail">
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    <span>Installed on 02 Dec 2017</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    <span>Chuni ka Pura</span>
                    <p>Morena, Madhya pradesh </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <i className="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                    <span>Irrigation Pump <b>2HP AC Surface</b></span>
                    <p>Solar Panel Capacity 300Wp </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div className="portal">
                <span>Visit portal</span><a href="/"><i className="fa fa-external-link-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      );
    }
  }

  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'MYAPI'
  })(MapContainer);
```

Below is the image of the screen to help u get in perspective of pins I m adding and why its the reason of slow load of infowindow of a marker.

[Map with pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXYhn.png)

SO, how can I resolve the above time taking render?
Will appreciate the help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this behavior the following component for markers could be introduced:

```
class MarkersList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.markersRendered = false;
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props.places) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.places) && this.markersRendered) {
      return false;
    }
    this.markersRendered = true;
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        {this.props.places.map((place, i) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              {...this.props}
              key={i}
              data={place}
              position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </span>
    )
  }

}
```

where re-rendering of markers is prevented in case if markers data have not been updated ([`shouldComponentUpdate` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate))

Here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bxuavz)

Comment: There is a bug in your above code. If you click on a marker, close the Infowindow and again click on same marker then you wont see the infowindow again

Comment: also includng the following solved the issue: onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}

Comment: I am facing exact same issue as you. I have did your changes and it is working!! Thansk. But one issue I am facing :  When I refresh web page (running on http://localhost:3000),  somehow 'markersRendered' flag becomes 'true' and no markes being shown on page refresh. Why? Any idea?  Note : constructor of this class  is called which make this flag false, but don't know why this flag converted to true, afterwords.